# Could not parse - org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I am deploying my application to Tomcat 6.0.20.

Application uses Hibernate as ORM, Spring, and JSF for web-tier.

I also made simple runner from main() method to test Spring-Hibernate collaboration. And it does work fine and hibernate.cfg.xml is parsed pretty well.

I can append some code or full stack trace but I'm not sure that it's necessary because Google says that it's typical problem and it's easy to recognize it from the title. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution..

So, who knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you don't have two different dom4j jars on your classpath.

Comment: like one in the tomcat system classpath and one in your webapp.

Comment: @bmargulies: Right. We **mustn't** put hibernate jars in Tomcat. Do put it in web app lib.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by excluding dom4j from hibernate entitymanager.

Also make sure you do `mvn clean` before.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.SP1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions> 
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved by adding dom4j to my `pom.xml` and making the scope provided

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It worked for me too. my configuration is spring **3.6.3.2.11.RELEASE**  **Hibernate 3.6.10.Final** running in **jboss-eap-4.3**