# WildFly DataSource Services which failed to start

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, wildfly

I configured a DataSource using WildFly to open a connection, but when I run WildFly I got this error:

```
11:47:46,874 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."services.war#DataSourceBLX": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."services.war#DataSourceBLX": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:33)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:27)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.workWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.<init>(XMLHelper.java:26)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:115)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:99)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:288)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
... 7 more

11:47:47,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)      WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."services.war#DataSourceBLX": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."services.war#DataSourceBLX": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
```

---

Here's my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="DataSourceBLX">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DataSourceBLX</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Alteracao</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Anuncio</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Avaliacao</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Categoria</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Contato</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Endereco</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Imagem</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.TipoUsuario</class>
    <class>com.brq.blx.entity.Usuario</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

And in my standalone

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DataSourceBLX" pool-name="OracleXE" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.2.8.224:1521:fundoshomo</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>70</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>stags</user-name>
                    <password>123</password>
                </security>
</datasource>
```

.

```
               <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                </driver>
```

I can't see what the problem is, so if you guys could help me, 
I would be grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not parse - org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804285/could-not-parse-org-dom4j-documentexception-org-dom4j-documentfactory-cannot)

Comment: It's not a data-source issue. You're more than likely including dom4j in your deployment.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I solved the problem by adding dom4j in my depencies and change oracle driver's name to just "jdbc" instead of "jdbc + [version]".