# Deploying Hibernate app to Wildfly 10 - org.dom4j.DocumentFactory ClassCastException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, gradle, wildfly

**UPDATE:** After destroying the WildFly instance and reconfiguring from scratch, the error has mysteriously resolved itself into a `org.hibernate.MappingException` for repeated columns.  Now that I actually know what the problem is, I can get to work fixing it.

---

I'm currently evaluating JPA backed by Hibernate in WildFly 10.  However, on attempting to deploy my test war (built by gradle) a seemingly irrelevant error is produced.  Here are the lines from the console log:

> 11:11:06,200 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management task-8) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "TestWar.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"TestWar.war#com.myapp.testwar.jpa\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"TestWar.war#com.myapp.testwar.jpa\": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"}}

From my `build.gradle`:

```
group 'com.myapp'
name 'TestWar'
version '0.0.0-dev'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
    provided group: 'javax.enterprise', name: 'cdi-api', version: '1.2'
    provided group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    provided group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.0.7.Final'
    provided group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.0.7.Final'
    provided group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: '5.0.7.Final'
    provided group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: '5.0.7.Final'
    provided group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    provided group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation', name: 'jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    provided group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb', name: 'jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    provided group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.sql', name: 'jboss-javax-sql-api_7.0_spec', version: '2.0.0.Final'
    provided group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs', name: 'jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec', version: '1.0.0.Final'
    provided group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4.1209'
}
```

I have tried the following solutions from similar posts on SO:

- [Making all dependencies provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35692287/1813169)
- [Adding `dom4j` to my dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25877129/1813169) (seems unnecessary since `gradle dependencies` shows it as a child of multiple hibernate libraries)
- [Ensure there is only one `dom4j` jar in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1804334/1813169) (there are no libraries in my war at all)

As well as these from other sources:

- [Adding `Dependencies: org.dom4j` to MANIFEST.MF](https://developer.jboss.org/message/630478#630478)
- [Adding `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with the following content:](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-5549)

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.dom4j"/>
    </dependencies>
    <local-last value="true"/>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Does anyone have any further suggestions, or have I done something monumentally stupid?

---

**Edit:** Apparently this error can be caused by any datasource configuration issues (see [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/756300#756300)).  For reference, the connection tests for my datasource via the admin console are successful, and the connection details are all correct as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You have a Problem with classloader

Comment: @Jens I'm not doing any classloading myself, although I am aware that WildFly is during deployment.  Could you expand on where the problem might be originating?

Comment: jboss has more than one classloader. So it Looks like you have dom4j jar multiple times on different classloaders

Comment: @Jens Okay, but where is this second instance coming from? This is a fresh instance of WildFly.  The only actions I've taken are to install the PostgreSQL JDBC driver as a deployed jar; configure my datasource, and attempt to deploy my test war.  It doesn't seem right that WildFly would ship with multiple instances of the same library

Comment: I do not know. Understanding classloading is very complicated

Comment: Look at the hibernate issue: [org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-5549)

Comment: Try removing all dependencies except for those that provide java-ee APIs, plus any additional class loading configuration that you have added. Your code should contain no references to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Nicholas That issue is where I found the last fix on my list (edited to include the link)

Comment: @SteveC That particular dependency was left over from my initial JDBC tests.  AFAIK, none of my existing code references it

Answer (score 1):

This error happens (at the moment) because you included `EntityManager` in your dependency list. Remove that. You shouldn't need it for normal operation.

See this Hibernate Jira on the issue: [org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-5549)

Comment: Since the error has now resolved itself, I can't test this now.  If it comes back, I'll give it a try though.  But why does this make a difference when the dependencies are all listed as provided?  None of them are actually copied to the war

Comment: The EntityManger jar has the old org.dom4j jar in it, so even though you may be getting it from wildfly, it still can't load.